# Add another Table in Where Clause

Tags: oracle

I am using Oracle DB.
I have a static query like

```
SELECT * FROM TESTSCHEMA.TABLE_A WHERE LOAN_ID = :LOAN_ID
```

The remaining where condition is coming from a table .

Now we came across a scenario where we need to introduce a new table if one column in TABLE_A is NULL i need to take value from TABLE_B
We are not looking for a code change or deployment , instead if we can update in table .

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TESTSCHEMA.TABLE_A
WHERE
    LOAN_ID = :LOAN_ID
    AND
    (
    /* if COLUMNA is NULL in TABLE_A
       then i need to pull value from TABLE_B in the same select statement */
    )
```

Comment: Lacks sufficent information to answer.  Mabe something like `SELECT A.*, coalesce(ColumnA, (Select columnB from TableB where Loand_ID = :Loan_ID)...`  But I'd rather left join to table_B and coaleace(ColumnA, columnb) as it's easier to maintain.  I'm not sure how you would do this w/o a code change to the select...

Comment: But as i mentioned i cannot change the select statement since its code dependent.

Comment: So you want to change the results of a query w/o changing the query?  not possible.

Comment: Well you are changing the where condition.

Comment: I Can modify only where clause , because where clause is coming from configuration table.

Comment: As xQbert said, you cant do that

Comment: so then `WHERE coalesce(ColumnA, (SELECT columnB from tableB where.... --Ensuring only a SINGLE value is returned always)= SomeValue`

Comment: it will be always one value . If you dont mind Can you post full query

Comment: @xQbert That doesnt bring tableB values on the select is only filtering the data

Comment: @Vinoy I can't as I don't know what the query to pull data back from table B and ensuring it is limited to a single value would look like.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza True.  I interperted the null as getting replaced with a value/variable from table B instead of the null value.  so `coalesce(NULL(ColumnA), 'SOMEBVALUE'(ColumnB)) = 'DESIREDVALUE'`

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please include sample data, as you can see two people can get different interpretation of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation...
If you're wanting to limit the data returned based on columnA when it has a value, but when it doesn't have a value (NULL) use columnB from table B... to limit by it; then coalesce & a sub query should do it.

Or you could replace the whole subquery with a scalar function and call it.

```
SELECT *
FROM TESTSCHEMA.TABLE_A
WHERE LOAN_ID = :LOAN_ID
  AND COALESCE(COLUMNA,(SELECT ColumNName 
                        FROM table_B 
                        WHERE [Some Limits to get 1 record always]) = DesiredValue
```

- Replace `ColumnName` with desired column from table_B
- Replace `DesiredValue` with value you want to compare columnA, or ColumnB to.
- Add Where clause limits to table_B to ensure you only get 1 record back always.

Or...

```
SELECT *
FROM TESTSCHEMA.TABLE_A
WHERE LOAN_ID = :LOAN_ID
  AND COALESCE(COLUMNA,GetBValueWhenAValueNull(Paramaters?)) = DesiredValue
```

But as that would require a deployment/code change... guessing not

Comment: Your interpretation is Correct . I am trying it .

Comment: This is the query i am trying now                                                                                    
    SELECT *
    FROM BLT.BLT_HDR_TRA 
    WHERE LOAN_ID = 4010
    AND COALESCE(INSTITUTION,(SELECT 123 FROM DUAL )) = NULL
    --INSTITUTION will be always NULL 
    -- SELECT 123 FROM DUAL , this query i will revisint according to bisiness condition and make sure only one valule returned

Comment: I'm confused.  if institution is null, you want to compare 123 to null.  which will never be true; it will never be false either... it will be NULL so you'll never get any records.  Juan's right we need sample data expected results.  It doesn't have to be real data; but it needs to highlight the problem you have.  Null can not be compared using `=` it's always `is null` or `not is null`

Comment: At this point use plain english to spell out what you're trying to accomplish.  Something like.  I want to see all records from tableA that match the LoanID I enter but exclude those records having a NULL columnA value except if ColumnB from TableB is not null?

Comment: The LOAN_ID is a primary key in BLT_HDR_TRA so this query will return  always a single result .
Now my requirement is to modify one value in select without altering the select Clause but i can modify the where clause.
INSTITUTION will be always NULL and i need to take another value from different table and show that value in select as INSTITUTION column value.
  
SELECT *
FROM BLT.BLT_HDR_TRA
WHERE LOAN_ID = 401014959
AND COALESCE(INSTITUTION,(value i need from another query ))

Comment: -- Sub query which need to pull the data
SELECT CASE WHEN  CORR_TI = 'B' THEN '12345' ELSE '54321' END AS INSTITUTION FROM BROKER CO,LOAN  LO WHERE LO.CORR_ID = CO.CORR_ID
AND LO.LOAN_ID = 4010

Comment: Can the done. You can't modify a value in the select from the where all you can do is filter data

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is remove the NULL values from tableA

```
UPDATE TABLE_A 
SET value = (SELECT TABLE_B.value 
             FROM TABLE_B
             WHERE TABLE_A.LOAN_ID  = TABLE_B.LOAN_ID  )
WHERE LOAN_ID = :LOAN_ID
AND  value is NULL
```